# User.Identity.Name empty

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication

I have a simple ASP.NET MVC application where I use Forms Authentication. I set the forms auth cookie when the Login button is clicked.

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie("userid",false);
```

The issue is that the subsequent requests have System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity always shows IsAuthenticated = false, and Name is empty. The [Authorize] attribute always fails due to this. However, I can see the the subsequent requests have the cookie .ASPXAUTH in the header. My Web.Config file has  `<authentication mode="Forms" />`

What could be the issue?

Comment: Did you create your project using the default MVC template?

Comment: @DavidG Yes. I used the default template

Comment: shouldn't you be using FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName,false);

Answer (score 0):

In your startup code, do you have something similar to this:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/account/login"),
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
                // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
                // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account.  
                OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, User, int>(
                    validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                    regenerateIdentityCallback: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager),
                    getUserIdCallback: (identity) => identity.GetUserId<int>()
                )
            }
        });
```

Pretty sure this was the solution when I had similar issues, but it was years ago, so I do not remember 100%.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that I had the below in my Web.config.

```
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
    </modules>
```

I commented this:

> `<!--<remove name="FormsAuthentication" />`-->

And it started working.